# How can i make Association rules considering count information?

Tags: r, count, associations

Hi now i'm studying association rules with R.
i have a question.

in transcation data, 
we consider just buy or non-buy (binary data)

i want to know how to perform association rules with count data

ex)

```
    item1 item2 item3
1   2     0     1
2   0     1     0
3   1     0     0
```

first customer bought two item1s!!

but in ordinary association rules, that count information is ignored
how can we consider that information?

Answer (score 0):

High, The quantitative association rules (QAR) mining may be helpful.

Firstly, you should divide the value field of every item to some sets and give every set an unique label. Then, the original dataset can be transformed to a binary dataset containing those labels.

for example, for item1, if the original data has the following information:

1. the first person have bought 5 item1s
2. the second one have bought 2 item1s
3. the third one have bought 7 item1s.

You can divide the value field of item1 to [0, 3), [3, 6) and [6, 9), and use a1, a2 and a3 to represent them, so the item 'item1' can be replaced by 3 other items, which are a1, a2 and a3, and the original data can be replaced by the follows.

1. the first person have bought one a2.
2. the second person have bought one a1.
3. the third person have bought one a3.

After doing this work on every item, the original dataset can be transformed to a binary dataset.

Comment: Edit your answer to include proper level of details.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have added some details